# superimposing axes on subplots in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have a nxn matplotlib subplot. Each subplot contains some timeseries plots. Each row of subplots corresponds to particular bin of variable 'second PC' and  column corresponds to a particular bin of another variable 'first PC'. I want to superimpose another axis ontop of the subplots (as shown in red in the figure) on which correpondng values of PCs are given. how can we do that?

[image]

Comment: Use inset_axes. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html